# Facebook like box, liking specific url

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-likebox

G'day,
I managed putting in the like button in there. Challenge is now when I press "like" it only likes the homepage, because that's where it's located. But this button is supposed to "like" the (blog)post which it's (not yet)directed to.

How to direct it to the post? Cheers

to visualize it: http://robertstam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/socialexample.jpg

```
<div class="meta">
                    <time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date(__('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', 'bunyad')); ?>" itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?> </time>

                    <?php echo apply_filters('bunyad_review_main_snippet', ''); ?>

         <?php if (strtolower(ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME_EN) == 'english'): ?>
         <?echo ('[fb_button]'); ?> 
         <?php endif; ?>

                    <span class="comments"><a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_comments_link());?>"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                        <?php echo get_comments_number();?></a></span>

                </div>
```

Comment: Is `[fb_button]` a shortcode?

Comment: @KaranKhanna facebook like plugin for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FB API reference for LIKE .   It may be possible that your 'fb_button' markup  does not hold the correct value for the link property. The 'link' may be pointed to your homepage instead of your specific post url.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

It would help if you post the codes behind 'fb_button'.

also, this is does not seem right.

```
<?echo ('[fb_button]'); ?>
```

Be consistent.. choose one of these ...

```
<?php echo('[fb_button]'); ?> // forgot php

<?="[fb_button]"?> // php short tags

<?php echo do_shortcode('[fb_button]'); ?> // to execute shortcode in a template
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the facebook like plugin before. Now with the facebook like button creator I added `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`in order to refer to the post

```
  <?php if (strtolower(ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME_EN) == 'english'): ?>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
    </div><?php endif; ?>
```